# Set array of wires to integer value in Verilog test bench

Tags: verilog

I am writing a test bench for a module that takes an array of inputs that represents a number using the following code:

```
module ComparatorTest;
wire [3:0] a;
wire [3:0] b;
output aHigher, bHigher, equal;

Comparator c (a, b, aHigher, bHigher, equal);

initial begin
    $dumpfile("test.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, ComparatorTest);

    # 0  a[3:0]=1111, b[3:0]=0000;
    # 20 a[3:0]=1111, b[3:0]=1111;
    # 40 a[3:0]=0000, b[3:0]=1111;
    # 60 $stop;
end
endmodule
```

I want to be able to set the arrays a and b either in base 10 or in binary like I would a number.  How do I go about doing this?  The code that I have gives me a syntax error (ComparatorTest.v:12: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `wire` to `reg` and you should be good to go.

And if you want to set them in binary, then you have to prefix with `4'b`, like so: `4'b0000`, `4'b1111`, etc.  The 4 indicates the number of bits.  If you want decimal, then do `4'd0`, `4'd15`, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Is setting the wires like that going to impact how I can do boolean algebra in the future?  For example can I do this "assign bHigher = !a[0]&b[0];" in the Comparator.v

Comment: Looks fine to me.